# H2 db for SpringBoot tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, h2

I am using Postgres database and I want to use H2 database for tests. The problem is when I'm creating new object in database, it seems that H2 is not used at all in test.

Test class:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest
 @AutoConfigureMockMvc
 @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
 @ActiveProfiles("test")
 public class CompanyTests {

@SpyBean
private CompanyService companyServiceMock;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;

@Test
@Transactional
public void testaaaa() {
    entityManager.persist(new Company("nnnn", new Address()));
    List<Company> all = companyServiceMock.findAll();
    all.forEach(company -> System.out.println(company.getName()));
}
```

application.properties:

```
 spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/EDI
 spring.datasource.username=postgres
 spring.datasource.password=password
 spring.datasource.platform=postgresql
 spring.datasource.initialize=true
 spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
 spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false

 spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
 spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
 spring.jpa.show-sql=true
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

application-test.properties:

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-        
1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

And when I use findAll() in my test, it lists all companies from postgresql and new which is created by entityManager.

Answer (score 0):

You should have separate properties files for `dev` and `test` profiles, in your case you should rename your `application.properties` to `application-dev.properties` and create `application.properties` file with only one property `spring.profiles.active=dev`

Comment: I've tried it before and it's still the same. :( and in application.properties i must have spring.queries.users and spring.queries.roles, but it doesn't important in this case I think

Comment: Do you have profiles section in your `pom.xml` with appropriate dependencies for each profile?

Comment: There is everywhere 'Cannot resolve' in project when I add dependencies to profiles. :/

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `@TestPropertySource(locations= "classpath:application-test.properties")` to the annotation? you should make it explicit for the test class that you are using the test **application.properties**.

This is late, but I'd be happy to be of some help.